# I am I am trying to connect Unity game to MongoDB but I have an error using an a async method and task, How can I solve that?

Tags: c#, mongodb, unity-game-engine

I am trying to connect mongolab to an application in Unity, but I have a problem in this line:

```
async static Task AsyncCrud(BsonDocument[] seedData)
```

The problem is here:

[image]

I wonder if someone can help me to solve this problem or suggest me another way to create the connection.

This is all the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

/*
 * Copyright (c) 2015 ObjectLabs Corporation
 * Distributed under the MIT license - http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 *
 * Written with CSharpDriver-2.0.0
 * Documentation: http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/
 * A C# class connecting to a MongoDB database given a MongoDB Connection URI.
 */

namespace MongoLab 

{
    class Simple
    {

        // Extra helper code
        static BsonDocument[] CreateSeedData()
        {
            BsonDocument seventies = new BsonDocument {
        { "Decade" , "1970s" },
        { "Artist" , "Debby Boone" },
        { "Title" , "You Light Up My Life" },
        { "WeeksAtOne" , 10 }
      };

            BsonDocument eighties = new BsonDocument {
        { "Decade" , "1980s" },
        { "Artist" , "Olivia Newton-John" },
        { "Title" , "Physical" },
        { "WeeksAtOne" , 10 }
      };

            BsonDocument nineties = new BsonDocument {
        { "Decade" , "1990s" },
        { "Artist" , "Mariah Carey" },
        { "Title" , "One Sweet Day" },
        { "WeeksAtOne" , 16 }
      };

            BsonDocument[] SeedData = { seventies, eighties, nineties };
            return SeedData;
        }//end create

        async static Task AsyncCrud(BsonDocument[] seedData)
        {
            // Create seed data
            BsonDocument[] songData = seedData;

            // Standard URI format: mongodb://[dbuser:dbpassword@]host:port/dbname
            String uri = "mongodb://usuario:pass@server.mongolab.com:puerto/basededatos";

            var client = new MongoClient(uri);
            var db = client.GetDatabase("learnygames");//debe de ser la base de datos existente
            Console.WriteLine(db);
            Console.WriteLine(client.GetDatabase("db"));

            /*
             * First we'll add a few songs. Nothing is required to create the
             * songs collection; it is created automatically when we insert.
             */

            var songs = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("songs");


            // Use InsertOneAsync for single BsonDocument insertion.
            await songs.InsertManyAsync(songData);
            Console.WriteLine("songs ********************************************");
            /*
             * Then we need to give Boyz II Men credit for their contribution to
             * the hit "One Sweet Day".
             */

            var updateFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Title", "One Sweet Day");
            var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("Artist", "Mariah Carey ft. Boyz II Men");

            await songs.UpdateOneAsync(updateFilter, update);

            /*
             * Finally we run a query which returns all the hits that spent 10
             * or more weeks at number 1.
             */

            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gte("WeeksAtOne", 10);
            var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Ascending("Decade");

            await songs.Find(filter).Sort(sort).ForEachAsync(song =>
              Console.WriteLine("In the {0}, {1} by {2} topped the charts for {3} straight weeks",
                song["Decade"], song["Title"], song["Artist"], song["WeeksAtOne"])
            );

            // Since this is an example, we'll clean up after ourselves.
          //  await db.DropCollectionAsync("songs");
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            BsonDocument[] seedData = CreateSeedData();
            AsyncCrud(seedData).Wait();
        }
    }//end class conexxion

}//end name space
```

Comment: Have you solve this problem? I have the same problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unity doesnt support the async keyword since it uses .Net 3.5.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261939/how-to-execute-async-task-in-unity3d).

You can do async operations with [coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I have learnt that Async isn't supported in Unity as another user has an highlighted as an answer.

### Update

I was also trying to implement an async call in unity which brought my search to this question. Further research I discovered that Async was not supported but I also had found a github project by Real Serious Games that implement promises which were their answer to implementing async in unity.

https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise

I first discovered their promise library from the unity knight's blog
http://blog.theknightsofunity.com/coroutines-unity-encapsulating-promises-part-1/
They have a 3/4 part article going over the basics and there is also a detail blog by Real Serious Games about the library on their blog.

I am now doing async by attaching the promise object to my unity coroutines to for async functionality.

### Original Answer

The error you've pictured is basically saying put the keyword static before async.

`static async Task AsyncCrud(BsonDocument[] seedData){}`

you may need to Template the Task type with your actual return type

`static async Task<T> AsyncCrud(BsonDocument[] seedData){}`